# How to manage large size file?

Tags: python, linux, mmap, memory-mapped-files

Disk file size of 600+ MB continuously appended by multiple agents.

Below code open and reads this large size file,

```
def alert_entries():
    with open('large_size_file') as f:
         ....
          ....
        for entry in entry_re.findall(f.read()):
            yield entry
```

Machine goes slow after opening this file.

---

How to manage opening and reading large size file, memory efficiently?

Comment: perhaps a better strategy could be to "tail" the file, read it as it grows.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Does memory mapping a file? use the memory efficiently..

Comment: A file rotation strategy with active file on ram disk/image?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz mmap() api

Comment: Could be that or something simpler with tmpfs setup.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Can u provide some python reference on using this strategy?

Comment: Unfortunately have no experience with mmap mysef, was just thinking out loud sorry.

Comment: Does your regex require the entire string? Or can it be applied line by line?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga regex can be aplied line by line. For performance reasons I said re.MULTILINE

Comment: Well then iterate line by line. It will sacrifice speed for performance. Alternatively, read large chunks and apply the regex on those chunks.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `f.read()` will read the whole thing in memory.  You can either iterate over the file directly `for line in f` (as mentioned in the comment below)  or pass an argument to read e.g. `read(size)` to limit how much you process in one go.

Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python) for an example using the latter approach.